# js getting months & years from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects:

```
let arr = [
    {date: '2021/01/23', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/11/21', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2020/12/22', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/12/08', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2020/12/14', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/10/25', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/12/04', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  ]
```

How can I filter array of objects for each month with year, like :

```
'December 21' = [
{date: '2021/12/04', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
{date: '2021/12/08', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' }
]

'January 21' = [
{date: '2021/01/23', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' }
]

'December 20' = [
{date: '2020/12/22', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' }
]
```

Thanks in advance!:)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO and elsewhere, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] showing your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: In particular, search thoroughly ("group" should be one of your search terms). There are **dozens** of answered questions about how to group array elements.

Comment: what is the expected result? Can you please update it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```js
// Your input
let arr = [
    {date: '2021/01/23', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/11/21', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2020/12/22', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/12/08', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2020/12/14', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/10/25', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
    {date: '2021/12/04', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
];

// Month dictionary
const monthNames = [ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June",
"July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" ];

// Get what you want
const result = arr.reduce((acc, el) => {
  // Extract year & month from date
  const [ year, month ] = el.date.split('/');
  // Get label in 'Month YY' format
  const label = monthNames[+month - 1] + ' ' + year.slice(2);
  // Add object key to result if necessary
  if (!acc[label]) acc[label] = [];
  // Save element
  acc[label].push(el);
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Refs: [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
const filterArr = (month, year) => arr.filter(x => {
  const splitDate = x.date.split('/');
  return splitDate[0] === year && splitDate[1] === month;
});

// Usage
filterArr("10", "2021");
```

EDIT: If you want to use the name of the month try this:

```
const monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July",
  "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const monthNameToNumber = (month) => (monthNames.indexOf(month) + 1)
      .toString().padStart(2, '0');

// Usage
monthNameToNumber("December"); // "12"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use forEach method to iterate from the array and save everything in an object. Like this:

```js
let arr = [
  {date: '2021/01/23', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2021/11/21', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2020/12/22', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2021/12/08', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2020/12/14', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2021/10/25', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  {date: '2021/12/04', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
];

filteredArr = {};

arr.forEach((obj) => {
  const newDate = new Date(obj.date);
  const stringMonthAndYear = newDate.toLocaleString('default', { month: 'long' }) + ' ' + newDate.getFullYear();

  if (filteredArr[stringMonthAndYear] && filteredArr[stringMonthAndYear].length) {
    filteredArr[stringMonthAndYear].push(obj);
  } else {
    filteredArr[stringMonthAndYear] = [obj];
  }
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const month = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

let arr = [
  { date: '2021/01/23', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2021/11/21', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2020/12/22', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2021/12/08', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2020/12/14', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2021/10/25', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
  { date: '2021/12/04', a1: 'text1', a2: 'text2' },
];

let obj = {};
for (const row of arr) {
  const date = new Date(Date.parse(row.date));
  let key = `${month[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`;
  if(!obj[key]) obj[key] = [];
  obj[key].push(row);
}
```